# How can I have a permanent status line showing the name of the current file?

Tags: vim

I keep on forgetting which file I'm editing.

In Vim 7.x, how can I have a permanent status bar at the bottom (like what is displayed when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) showing the current file name I'm editing?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[From the manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27statusline%27), you're really just wanting:

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%f "tail of the filename
```

As an aside: if you're wanting a status line with a ton more information be sure to
check out [this link](http://got-ravings.blogspot.com/2008/08/vim-pr0n-making-statuslines-that-own.html). It'll give you something a bit more fancier like so:-

[image]

Comment: @anon: Add these lines to your `.vimrc` (or `_vimrc` on Windows).

Comment: This works after setting it in .vimrc file. Can someone please tell me how I can force this to be displayed on the top?

Answer (score 16):

You can use [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#CTRL-G) to print the current file name along with the cursor position and the file status.

To permanently show the current filename (and much more) in the statusline, you can use the [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) plugin. By default, the statusline will look similar to this:

[image]