# How to activate the status / info bar at the bottom in vi?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vi

i'm using Ubuntu 20.04 as a virtual machine and don't know how to activate the bottom info bar in vi.

I have made an image how it should look like (this image is a cutting from a vi edited file where it looks like i want it to):

[image]

I want to have this line, but in my ubuntu vm this is not there. (So I  need to activate the line where it is shown where the pointer is, and which command i am having as an Input right now -> this is the 22 in the image where i wanted to jump to line 22 with G)

Thanks, Carl

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suited for [vi.se] (but check their rules first).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404879/how-can-i-have-a-permanent-status-line-showing-the-name-of-the-current-file

Comment: In any case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404879/how-can-i-have-a-permanent-status-line-showing-the-name-of-the-current-file has your answer.